# Win 10 SOLR indexing

Tags: java, windows, solr

I am trying to index the exampledocs that come with SOLR using post.jar.  I created a collection example_docs. When I issue the command

```
java -jar post.jar -c example_docs c:\solr6.4.2\example\exampledocs
```

It complains "specifying either the url or core/collection is mandatory."  I thought the -c argument did that.  When I look at the help output from post.jar, it says the command is -Dc, but that gives the same result.  What an I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on a comment to [this page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Post+Tool).  From the exampledocs folder:

```
java -Dc=example_docs -Dauto=yes -Ddata=files -Drecursive=yes -jar post.jar *
```